# Entity Framework Update Reference

Tags: c#, wcf

Might be my question is basic.
I am not sure about some thing that is why asking.
I have a project in which I define a model Class Foo. It contains only Models.
Created a WCF Service in Service project which use Model Foo.
and then Created a Client added the reference of Model Foo to Client Project
later added service Reference by checking radio button
"Reuse types in referenced assemblies" 
Now the question is what is the benefit of reusing assembly.?
2ndly , If i update the foo Class properties then I need to update 
the Service reference too  in Client Project ?
or it is ok if not update the Service Reference.
here i Would like to tell you that change made only in the Foo model I.E
added or renamed a property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link should answer your 1st question - [Reuse types in referenced assemblies](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/859c5014-bbad-486a-ac8f-c3b6058c32a9/what-does-reuse-types-in-referenced-assemblies-mean?forum=wcf)

As for 2nd question, you don't need to update the Client so long as there is no change in the interfacing structure of your class. What I mean by that is, as long as only the internal details of a class changes, you don't need to update the reference. By your description given above, you are updating the properties, so you NEED to update the Client.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But the thing which made me confuse.I Just added new Property 
in Foo Build the Project.. updated foo Reference in both Service 
and Client it was ok..  New Property was Populated correctly in Client.

Comment: Did you create your service and client in the same project ?

Comment: not same project,but in the same solution. cause each project is separate. I.E  Foo Model Project, Service Project, Client Project.

Comment: Yup sorry, I meant same solution. 
It will obviously work as you have structured it. You have given reference of Foo project to both Service and Client. So, this will work. Both service and client will take the updated reference as soon as you build the Foo project.
If you don't give the Foo reference to the Client and allow it to come through the Service reference then you need to explicitly update it.

I hope this clears your doubt.

Comment: Let me Clear, Here updating the reference means updating the Service Reference, i am okay with updating foo Class Reference.
the question about updating the Service Reference. is it required to update service reference when i change the Foo Class Model.

Comment: " If i update the foo Class properties then I need to update the Service reference too in Client Project ? " from question.

Comment: If you have a reference of Foo in Client project then you NEED NOT update the Service reference.

If you do not have a reference of Foo in Client project then you NEED to update the Service reference.


Going by your description, you NEED NOT update the service reference.